# Netbeans set root as author

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 cinnamon 64 bits

I just downloaded Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0

It wasn't necessary to run any script to install it, i just had to run the following command to launch it: `sudo /opt/netbeans/bin/netbeans`
Then enter my password and netbeans opens.
Then i made a launcher for the program because i didn't want to type the command and my password every time i open netbeans.
But the launcher didn't worked.
I realize that i didn't put "sudo" in the command that the launcher would execute so i put it. And didn't work.

I thought that it wasn't working because the launcher executes `sudo /opt/netbeans/bin/netbeans` but don't put the password.
After some research i end up adding `star_man ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/netbeans/bin/netbeans` at the end of `/etc/sudoers` and it finally works. But when i create a new project Netbeans sets root as the author of every file it creates.

For example, when i type `ls -l` in my project directory it outputs this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3527 sep 15 20:01 build.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 sep 15 20:01 manifest.mf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 sep 15 20:01 nbproject
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 sep 15 20:01 src
```

Root is the group and the owner of every file an directory.

This causes that when Netbeans generates documentation files it put "root" instead my username.

**Update:**
I only can start neatbeans as root (sudo ./netbeans).

when i run neatbean without `sudo` from the terminal it looks like it's starting:[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2MHy.png)

but then it closes.

This is the output:

```
>Log Session: Sunday, September 16, 2018 at 12:58:20 PM Eastern Daylight Time
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708)
  Operating System        = Linux version 4.15.0-34-generic running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 10.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 10.0.1+10; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 10.0.1+10
  Java Home               = /opt/java/jdk-10.0.1
  System Locale; Encoding = es_DO (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/star_man
  Current Directory       = /opt/netbeans
  User Directory          = /home/star_man/.netbeans/9.0
  Cache Directory         = /home/star_man/.cache/netbeans/9.0
  Installation            = /opt/netbeans/nb
                            /opt/netbeans/ide
                            /opt/netbeans/extide
                            /opt/netbeans/java
                            /opt/netbeans/apisupport
                            /opt/netbeans/websvccommon
                            /opt/netbeans/profiler
                            /opt/netbeans/harness
                            /opt/netbeans/javafx
                            /opt/netbeans/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = 
  Application Classpath   = /opt/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /opt/netbeans/platform/core/core-base.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/core/asm-all-5.0.1.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/opt/netbeans/platform/core/core.jar:/opt/netbeans/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/opt/netbeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/opt/netbeans/
!SESSION 2018-09-16 12:58:21.698 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=es_DO

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-09-16 12:58:21.706
!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: Permission denied
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2090)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.initializeInstanceFile(StorageManager.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:61)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:115)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1331)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1148)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:315)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:125)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:282)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Permission denied
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:61)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:115)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1331)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1148)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:315)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:251)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:125)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:282)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2090)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.initializeInstanceFile(StorageManager.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    ... 16 more
```

I find out that every file and directory under `~/.netbeans` has root as owner and group. I thought that might be the problem so i changed the owner and group with `~/.netbeans $ sudo chown -R myusername: .netbeans/`. And still i'm only able to run netbeans as root.

Comment: This seems more like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see why this can't be here

Comment: @LewisMojica Your question is definitely fine here, and it clearly falls in a category that is specifically mentioned in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!_

Comment: Just to note that two people have (incorrectly) voted to close this question because _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"_. This question clearly relates to _**"tools used primarily for programming"**_, so it is on topic.

Comment: This question is not about a programming tool; it's about general unix  permissions.

Comment: @skomisa - You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*. I think it is a bit of a stretch to claim managing ACLs and setting permissions is unique to software development.

Comment: @jww I didn't miss that part - I specifically and deliberately quoted it. NetBeans is clearly a programming tool, and the poster's issue is specifically **within** NetBeans: _"when i create a new project **NetBeans sets root as the author of every file it creates**"_. I think it is _"a bit of stretch"_ to claim that this problem isn't clearly a NetBeans problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic unix permissions problem.

For reasons that escape me, you used `sudo` to launch the `netbeans` IDE.
  - You should not have done that.
  - You should not have **needed** to do that!

When you use `sudo` to run something, you are typically running as the `root` user.  (That is what `sudo` does!)

So, naturally, the something (in this case, the `netbeans` application run using `sudo`) will create files and directories owned by the "root" user.  So when you try to update them as a normal user, the operating system says "Nope: you don't own those files / directories, so you can't modify them.".

Solution: use the `chown` command to change the ownership of the files and the directories as required.

How?  Read `man chown`, or look for a tutorial on how to change the ownership of a file.

- Hint: you will need to use `sudo` when chowning ...
- Hint 2: be very, very careful when you use `sudo`, because `sudo` has the power to trash your system if you make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for answering!. I only can run netbean as root (sudo ./netbeans). If i try "./netbeans" it doesn't start.

Comment: I find out that every file under ~/.netbeans has root as owner, so i changed the owner and group from root to my username with chown, but still i only can run it as root

Comment: The partial stacktrace says that your Netbeans is trying to create a temporary file (a lock file probably) in a directory where it doesn't have write permission.  Find that directory and fix its ownership and/or permissions.

Comment: Since you are running on Linux, check ~/.netbeans and subdirectories.

Comment: I executed `sudo chown -R myusername: ~/.netbeans` , so the owner of every file and directory under `~/.netbeans` is `myusername`. Still doesn't works.

Comment: Per the full stacktrace, OSGI is trying to create an instance file in the storage manager's MANAGER_FOLDER.  Look for a directory called ".manager".  I suspect that this is actually in your Netbeans installation directory.  Which suggests that the problem is that your Netbeans installation has the wrong owner!

Comment: It works!. I runned `~ $ find | grep -w  .manager`. That returned `./.cache/netbeans/9.0/netigso/org.eclipse.equinox.app/.manager` so i runned `~ $ sudo chown -Rc star_man: ./.cache/netbeans/*` to set `myusername` as owner of every file under `~/.cache/netbeans/`. Thaks a lot.